# Validating user input Python

Tags: python

i am new to Python, and i was wondering if i could get some help with  a script. I am trying to validate user input with this script. I would like to restrict the user input to only integers for the number of minutes including and between 1 and 10080. I am still learning all of the terminology, but Here is what i have so far. It looks like something keeps getting stuck at `while True:`, but i can't seem to figure out what. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Min=int(input("Please enter the amount of minutes used as an integer ")
while True:
    try:
        Min = int(input('Min'))
        if Min < 1 or Min > 10080:
             raise ValueError
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid number of minutes. Please try again. ")
```

Comment: You're missing a `)` on the first line. Please make sure to include any errors you get so we can accurately help you though.

Comment: I feel so stupid. Thanks! btw the error i got was invalid syntax

Comment: Other than the fact that the first user input is disregarded, this code seem to be working fine. To solve that error I would replaced the first line with `print('Please enter ...')` and replaced the `'Min'` in line 4 with something more intuitive like `'>>> '`.

Comment: Don't raise an error to catch it in the same block.

Answer (score 3):

If you fix the syntax error on the first line (missing `)`) it should work, but it still asks for user input twice. Removing the first line and doing some minor cleanup, we can get:

```
while True:
    try:
        minimum = int(input("Enter number of minutes: "))
        if minimum < 1 or minimum > 10_080:
             raise ValueError
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid number of minutes. Please enter a value between 1 and 10,080.")
```

Comment: for anyone reading this and wondering about `10_080`, take a look at [PEP 515](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0515/). the underscores act as a visual separator and have no effect on parsing the value.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with @MatthewProSkills solution, but his version doesn't account for exceptions. Other answers don't save the variable. Here's an improved version.

```
minimum = 0
while minimum < 1 or minimum > 10080:
    try:
        minimum = int(input("Please enter the amount of minutes used as an integer "))
    except Exception:
        print("Invalid number of minutes. Please try again. ")
```

Comment: you shouldn't use bare `except` statements. better to be more precise about the error being caught, or at least use `except Exception`

Comment: @KosayJabre or, trailing underscore, `min_`, i've seen a lot

Comment: @KosayJabre I think those are just conventions, but I changed them anyway for the sake of it

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Run it

Comment: They're mostly conventions, except for that top-level identifiers that begin with an `_` aren't imported when the containing module is imported using a wildcard `import *`. Arguably, if `min` was a top-level identifier, it would be *better* for it to start with an underscore so that it doesn't pollute the namespace of the importing module. Also, instance attributes that begin with a `_` are often regarded as "private" by linters, and raise warnings if they're accessed from outside of the class.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Interesting, I didn't know that